# PyQt5 - Buttons and Label shall have the same height

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

it's a simple application. Just one label and three buttons. But the layout is making me trouble.

I want to have the childlayout for the label and the childlayout for the buttons to have the same height. But I can't get it to work. Neither with BoxLayouts nor with GridLayouts. I tried to addStretch, so both layouts have the same stretchfactor, and various different stuff. I'm sure the answer is easy but I can't figure it out.
I also tried it in QtDesigner, so I could inspect and compare the codeparts, but:

I designed this

[image]

and got this when running the code, again the buttons stick to the bottom and dont have the same height as the label

[image]

However, here's my code:

(I know that the Grid Layout is not necessary here, it was just some sort of trying to solve the problem. Anyways I don't think that the Grid Layout is the problem, as I had the same problems with BoxLayouts or just the label without a layout.)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QGroupBox, \
    QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 50, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Fretboard Note Quiz")

        self.layout()

        self.show()

    def layout(self):
        glay = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(glay)

        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()       #upper layout for label
        hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()       #bottom layout for buttons

        btn1 = QPushButton("1")
        btn2 = QPushButton("2")
        btn3 = QPushButton("3")

        #adding the buttons to the bottom layout
        hbox2.addWidget(btn1)
        hbox2.addWidget(btn2)
        hbox2.addWidget(btn3)


        label = QLabel("Text")
        hbox1.addWidget(label)

        glay.addLayout(hbox1, 0, 1)
        glay.addLayout(hbox2, 1, 1)
        glay.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        glay.setRowStretch(1, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the simplest thing is to use a QWidget as a container since by default they are stretched in the same way as the QLabel, so they will try to occupy the same space.

The problem with your initial code is that the stretch factors do not apply to layouts but to widgets.

Finally `layout()` is a method so do not hide it using it for other things, the names of the functions should describe the action of the method.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 50, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Fretboard Note Quiz")

        self.build_layout()

    def build_layout(self):
        btn1 = QPushButton("1")
        btn2 = QPushButton("2")
        btn3 = QPushButton("3")

        label = QLabel("Text")

        button_container = QWidget()
        hlay = QHBoxLayout(button_container)
        hlay.addWidget(btn1)
        hlay.addWidget(btn2)
        hlay.addWidget(btn3)

        vlay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlay.addWidget(label)
        vlay.addWidget(button_container)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set the minimunHeight of your buttons like:

```
ui.pushButton.setMinimumHeight(100)
```